# Does Spring have an annotation to read classpath contents to a String?

Tags: java, spring, io

I want to read the contents of a file in the classpath (in `resources/`) to a `String`. Does Spring have a convenience annotation for that?

Something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Resource("classpath:data.txt")
    private String data;
}
```

Is something like that available in Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Value("classpath:data.txt")
private Resource data;
```

You can't inject a `String`, but you can use a Spring abstraction called [`Resource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) to obtain a file and read its content on your own.

I think Spring places that responsibility on you because otherwise it would very fragile; different IO things may happen during accessing/reading a resource resulting in an `IOException`.

In addition, file-to-string conversions aren't that common to make Spring implement it.

Answer (score 1):

The [@Value annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) is used to inject property values into variables, usually Strings or simple primitive values. You can find more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

If you want to load a resource file, use a [ResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Autowired
    private CountWords countWords;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Count words : " + countWords.getWordsCount(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:file.txt")));

    }
}
```

Another solution, you can to use **@Value** like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Value("classpath:file.txt")
    private Resource res;

    @Autowired
    private CountWords countWords;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Count words : " + countWords.getWordsCount(res));

    }
}
```